# Transparent row of pixels between section header and first cell in a grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, uikit, transparent, uitableview

As the title says, I have a problem with a row of transparent pixels that I can't get rid off.
I attached an image as it's worth 1000 words.

[image]

The problem is not present for the section footer (where I'm also using a custom view).
I have checked and double checked that I return the correct size for the height of the section.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**
I've added a test project so you can play around. The purple color represents the background color. The white rectangles are the header/footer and the light gray are some dummy cells. The issue is clearly visible in the project.

[TransparentRowBug XCode project](https://www.2shared.com/file/R0oCuu0e/TransparentRowBug.html)

You will also see that I use a lot of clear colors. Unfortunately changing the colors in order to hide the problem is not a viable solution for me.

Feel free to give it a try (or more)!

Thanks a lot!

**EDIT2:**
After further investigation, I concluded that the line of pixels come from the tableview separator. In the test project I am setting the separatorColor to clearColor. If I change this to another color, I will get exactly that row of pixels in the new color. Even though I set the separator style to none, it seems to have no effect on grouped tables.

Comment: Have you tried returning 10pixels less than your needed height?

Comment: Yes. The behavior is somehow undetermined. The header view will appear cropped, but the transparent row will still be there sometimes. If i scroll away and come back, I will get a white row, or a black row (probably something from the cropped area) or a transparent row.  I even tried extending the UIImage in the header view beyond the view and removed the "clip subviews" flag on the idea that I can somehow cover that space. No luck :(

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I finally figured this one out, after almost 2 days of testing (and hair loss).

As I said in my comment above, simply returning a smaller height in the heightForHeader method doesn't work. To make it work you need to take your desired header view, insert it in a dummy/container view with the exact same size and then give this container to the tableView as the header.

Then, when you return a smaller size for the header, it magically (and it really is magic for me) manages to overlap that annoying row of pixels.

By the way, I concluded that the row of pixels is due to the cell separator line.

If someone is interested, I can upload the working test project again.

Comment: I had exactly the same problem (which is definitely an iOS bug) and merely returning my header view inside a dummy UIView solved the problem, without having to return a smaller size for the header. At the end of `viewForHeaderInSection` I have: `UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:[headerView frame]]; [view addSubview:headerView]; return view;`

Comment: In my case I'm using storyboards and the header view I'm returning is actually a prototype `UITableViewCell` created in IB. I suspected that the problem only occurred if the type of the header view was a `UITableViewCell`, and so I tested just returning a blank (but coloured) `UIView` and sure enough, the lines disappeared. So wrapping the `UITableViewCell` inside a `UIView` gets around the bug. Apple must be doing something slightly different if the header view's type is `UITableViewCell` that causes the separator to appear.

Comment: The method ask for a UIView, than the UITableViewCell is a subclass of UIView. I solve the problem just returning the UITableViewCell.contentView;

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to understand if that's what you're asking, but I figured two days ago that you can reduce default space between sections in a tableView...

By making `heightForHeader` returning a **negative value**! Dirty, but... works.

I hope that help...

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem too. I had a UITableView with grouped sections. Between the first section header and first cell, there was a 1-point (2 Retina pixels) gap where the background bled through.

If the background cell color is uniform, then you can assign the backgroundColor of the UITableView to hide this gap.

In my case, the backgroundColor/backgroundView was used for a non-scrolling patterned background on other cells. The solution proposed by mluisbrown works perfectly. I would like to re-emphasize this solution:

```
-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   UIView* topTabView = /* initialized elsewhere */;
   CGRect sectionHeaderSize = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 46);
   UIView* wrapperView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:sectionHeaderSize];
   topTabView.frame = sectionHeaderSize;
   [wrapperView addSubview:topTabView];
   return wrapperView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a separator between header view and first row :- In view for Header in section delegate method add a subview self.separator //@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *separator;

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

return 41; 
}


- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

self.headerView = [[UIView alloc] init];
self.headerView.backgroundColor = [UIUtils colorForRGBColor:TIMESHEET_HEADERVIEW_COLOR];

self.separator = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"seperator.png"]];
self.separator.frame = CGRectMake(0,40,self.view.frame.size.width,1);
[self.headerView addSubview:self.separator];
return self.headerView;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Grouped UITableView will take header, cell and footer as a single entity. So the white transparent view is the footer view which can be dealt by decreasing the footer height as shown in the screenshot. I hope it works 
Good Luck :)